# How to attach 'dblclick' to an element but not its descendants?

Tags: jquery

I have a basic list-item with an embedded list that I'd like to open when I double click anywhere in the li that isn't the embedded ul.

```
<ul>
    <li class="first_level">
        <span class="name">List Name</span>
        <ul class="tools"></ul>
        <ul class="sublist">
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
            <li>Subitem 2</li>
            <li>Subitem 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the example above I would like to have any where in .first_level to be attached to dblclick to toggle the .sublist to visible and not visible but I don't want this to happen if I dblclick on .tools, .sublist, or .name.

Basic code:

```
$('.first_level, .first_level :not(*)').dblclick(function(e){
    $(this).find('.sublist').toggle();
});
```

I thought my :not(*) would tell it not to attach it to the children but it didn't work. My .first_level has a min-height so my initial idea also had me check the coordinates of the click event within the element and if it was within the min-height to toggle. That solved the problem of it grabbing in the sublist but my tools and name was still a problem (not the best solution but it was succint). So what selector am I forgetting to use here?

http://jsfiddle.net/8PNEn/1/

Comment: what about binding dblclick to 'span.name'?

Comment: I'll be binding a different clicking event to the name (to edit the name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably going to have to do a little bit of logic in your handler, rather than relying on the selector.  Perhaps this, using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) and [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
$('.first_level').dblclick(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('li').is(this)) {
        $(this).find('.sublist').toggle();
    }
});
```

This starts from the event target (the element that was double-clicked), then traverses up the tree to find the nearest `li` element, and then sees whether that `li` element is the element where the function is handled, i.e. `.first_level`. If it is, then the sublist is toggled.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8PNEn/5/)

Comment: This is perfect. I added a bit of logic so that the target can only be a list-item to avoid opening on both spans :)

Answer (score 5):

Just make sure the double-click is done on `.first_level`

```
$('.first_level').dblclick(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('first_level')) {
        $(this).find('.sublist').toggle();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8PNEn/9/

Comment: i have a question. why won't this work to make the logic if(!($(this).hasClass("sublist")))

Comment: In the question, he says he doesn't want it to happen when clicking the .name element (the span).

Comment: It was hard to pick the "right" answer for this problem since there were a few possibilities. I ended up using a hybrid of this one and the currently accepted answer. My problem was that in my actual published code I don't actually have .first_level so my if only has if(this == e.target) and it works like a charm without any other checks on the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried canceling the event propagation for the name tools and sublist dom?  It would look something like this:

```
// attach double click to first level dom
$('.first_level').dblclick(function(e){
    $(this).find('.sublist').toggle();
});

// cancel even propagation for name, tools, and sublist dom
$('.name, .tools, .sublist').dblclick(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DbuQ5/

Answer (score 0):

Would that be a good way to do it : http://jsfiddle.net/DavidLaberge/8PNEn/6/

Comment: I thought of a solution like this one but the name will be editable so a double-click on the name would bring up the input box.

Answer (score 0):

Because my live code doesn't actually have the .first_level class I ended up using a hybrid solution between the accepted answer and the one that currently has the most up-votes. I decided to post my solution as an answer and not edit my question just to stay consistent with the site's functionality :)

```
$('ul > li').dblclick(function(e) {
    if (e.target == this) {
        $(this).find('.sublist').toggle();
    }
});
```